# What to do with the [format] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [format](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format) tag has no tag wiki.

The (currently) 7 questions seem to use it with different meanings (formatting of text, file formats, etc.).

What to do with the tag? Get rid of it? Define it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“Format” is a clear case of ambiguous meaning. We need to retag the questions to either remove [format](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format) or replace it by a non-ambiguous tag.

- [Songbook text processing: Repeat chord lines for recurrent parts automatically?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/470/songbook-text-processing-repeat-chord-lines-for-recurrent-parts-automatically) — I think [music](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) and [word-processor](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-processor) are enough (this isn't [plain-text](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plain-text) since it's about how the text is presented).
- [PHP verify .doc/.docx document respects template](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4294/php-verify-doc-docx-document-respects-template) — [format](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format) is pointless. [office](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office) [needs disambiguation](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1193/the-tag-office-needs-disambiguation).
- [Editing ofm format](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6926/editing-ofm-format) — That's about the Omniform format, so tag it [omniform](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/omniform).
- [Recover data from a diskpart > clean command](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7110/recover-data-from-a-diskpart-clean-command) — That's about data recovery. We already have [hdd-recovery](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hdd-recovery) and [recovery](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery) for that. Those need cleanup as well; I've retagged a couple of [recovery](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery) questions which weren't about recovery, and the rest were all about recovering deleted files or damaged filesystems (which overlaps a lot), so I merged them both into [data-recovery](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery) which is the tag name used on other Stack Exchange sites ([SF](https://serverfault.com/tags/data-recovery), [SU](https://superuser.com/tags/data-recovery), [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery), [Sec.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery), [Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery), [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery), …).
- [Format code for entire team](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16292/format-code-for-entire-team) — That's about [code-beautification](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-beautification) which is already present.
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16830/should-i-really-use-exfat-on-sdxc — That's about filesystems. The question is closed, unanswered, abandoned, so I deleted it.
- [Non-GPL non-proprietary non-viral-licensed popular video codec?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19428/non-gpl-non-proprietary-non-viral-licensed-popular-video-codec) — That's about video file formats. I'm changing [format](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format) to [file-format](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-format), though I this should really be [video-file](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-file) or something like it.

The tag is no more.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs ??? Where do I mention an answer having tags?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs *sigh* Edited.