# The tag [office] needs disambiguation

Tags: discussion, tags

[office](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office) is used to mean:

- Microsoft Office — use [microsoft-office](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office).
- OpenOffice/LibreOffice — use [openoffice](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openoffice)/[libreoffice](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice) instead.
- I'm looking for an office suite — use [office-suite](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-suite)?
- Other meanings?

Let's get rid of the bare “office” tag, because it's too ambiguous. It isn't suitable for “I'm looking for an office suite” because it gets too much misuse for questions about X Office.

Answer (score 2):

Even though [office-suite](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-suite) might sound like "*The Microsoft Office suite*" to some people, it would indeed be a good thing to:

- Get rid of [office](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office)
- Move agnostic questions to [office-suite](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-suite)
- Create a good tag wiki for [office-suite](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-suite)

Answer (score 1):

Out of the 4 first questions under the "office tag", 3 are suite-agnostic, and one even doesn't fit in office-suite as it asks for an iOS office app.

I think the tag, though it could be better used, is not worthless.